# PHP code that displays all links on a web page

Tags: php

I found this code [here](https://www.codexworld.com/extract-all-urls-from-web-page-using-php/)

```
<?php
$urlContent = file_get_contents('https://www.google.co.il/searchq=cow&rlz=1C1SQJL_iwIL827IL82&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje7-3q8uPiAhUG_qQKHdWAACwQ_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=578');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($urlContent);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++){
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    // validate url
    if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false){
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a><br />';
    }
}

?>
```

I do not understand why when I run it it brings me only the links of the page and it does not bring me the links of the images

Comment: Because it only get anchor tags (links) with `"/html/body//a"` and it only gets `href` property of the anchor tags.

Comment: Can you help me with what changes in this code please?

Comment: this is not upwork

Answer (score 0):

For all my crawlers I use this class https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/
Try it.

Comment: I tried to paste the code there, but I get a fatal error,
I read a lot about "evaluate"
But I do not know how to handle it, myself, hope in the future ....
Can anyone kindly describe to me the basis for the code for all links to images?
I've been working for a few hours, I'm not lazy, I'm just trying to gather knowledge - I guess I do not know enough to do a search on the Internet in this matter :(
Thank you!